# Как в двумерном масиве найти минимальный элемент по диагонали?

Tags: java, массивы, поиск

Смог создать и вывести двумерный массив. Как найти пока ума не приложу))

```java
public class ProjectSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = {
                {1, 2, 4, 5, 6},
                {1, 4, 5, 6, 7},
                {4, 5, 8, 8, 6},
                {5, 6, 3, 2, 1},
                {1, 5, 6, 7, 8}
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println()
```

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое "побочной диагонали"?

Comment: Исправил, так было в задании указано ))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int minDiag = array[0][0];
for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) 
  minDiag = Math.min(minDiag, array[i][i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// для главной диагонали
int min = array[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (min > array[i][i]) {
        min = array[i][i];
    }
}
System.out.println(min);

// для побочной диагонали
int min1 = array[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (min1 > array[array.length - 1 - i][i]) {
        min1 = array[array.length - 1 - i][i];
    }
}
System.out.println(min1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой задачи нам необходимо пройтись по всем элементам диагонали и найти минимум в ней. Так как нумерация всех таких элементов `array[i][i]`, то нам достаточно использовать один цикл и пройтись по всей диагонали.

```java
int mins = 1000; // задаем значение заведомо больше, чем все элементы массива
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    mins = Math.min(array[i][i], mins); // Math.min() - минимум из двух
}
System.out.print(mins);
```